# automatically insert only one row in table after calculating the sum of column

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

i have 3 table in my database

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  depances (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
            type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            nom VARCHAR,
            montant DECIMAL(100,2) NOT NULL,
            date DATE,
            temp TIME)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY  UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            montant DECIMAL(100,2), 
            medecin VARCHAR,
            patient VARCHAR, 
            acte VARCHAR,
            date_d DATE, 
            time_d TIME,
            users_id INTEGER)
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  total_jr (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
            total_revenu DECIMAL(100,2),
            total_depance DECIMAL(100,2),
            total_différence DECIMAL(100,2),
            date DATE)
```

my idea is to insert defrent value in table depances and transaction using a GUI interface.
and after that adding the SUM of montant.depances in total_depance.total_jr
and the SUM of montant.transactions in total_revenu.total_jr where all rows have the same time
that's the easy part using this code

```
self.cur.execute( '''SELECT SUM(montant) AS totalsum FROM depances WHERE date = %s''',(date,))
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        for i in result:
            o = i[0]
        
        self.cur_t = self.connection.cursor()

        self.cur_t.execute( '''INSERT INTO total_jr(total_depance) 
            VALUES (%s)'''
        , (o,))
        self.connection.commit()

        self.cur.execute( '''UPDATE total_jr SET total_depance = %s WHERE date = %s''',(o, date))
        self.connection.commit()
```

But every time it adds a new row to the table of total_jr

How can i add thos value of SUM(montant) to the table where the date is the same every time its only put the value of sum in one row not every time it add a new row
The result should will be like this

```
id|total_revenu|total_depance|total_différence|date
--+------------+-------------+----------------+----
1  sum(montant1) value         value            08/07/2020
2  sum(montant2) value         value            08/09/2020
3  sum(montant3) value         value            08/10/2020
```

but it only give me this result

```
id|total_revenu|total_depance|total_différence|date
--+------------+-------------+----------------+----
1   1           value         value            08/07/2020
2   2           value         value            08/07/2020
3   3           value         value            08/7/2020
```

if there is any idea or any hit that will be hulpefull

Comment: . . A `select` does not add rows to a table.

Comment: yes i just put that to show how i calculate the SUM `self.cur.execute( '''SELECT SUM(montant) AS totalsum FROM depances WHERE date = %s''',(date,))
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        for i in result:
            o = i[0]
        
        self.cur_t = self.connection.cursor()

        self.cur_t.execute( '''INSERT INTO total_jr(total_depance) 
            VALUES (%s)'''
        , (o,))
        self.connection.commit()` this is my complet code od calculating the SUM and it work correctly

Comment: my problem is how to add a row automatically to the table with only one value of date (the will be not 2 row with the same date that's all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution for anyone who need it in future first of all we need to update the table

```
        create_table_total_jr = ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  total_jr (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
            total_revenu DECIMAL(100,2),
            total_depance DECIMAL(100,2),
            total_différence DECIMAL(100,2),
            date DATE UNIQUE)''' #add unique to the date
```

and after that we use the UPSERT and ON CONFLICT

```
 self.cur_t.execute( ''' INSERT INTO total_jr(date) VALUES (%s)
        ON CONFLICT (date) DO NOTHING''', (date,))
        self.connection.commit()
```

with this code when there is an insert value with the same date it will do nothing
after that we update the value of the SUM

```
 self.cur.execute( '''UPDATE total_jr SET total_depance = %s WHERE date = %s''',(o, date))
        self.connection.commit()
```

Special thanks to Mike67 for his help

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which DBMS or SQL module you're using so I'm guessing MySQL.

In your process, run the update first and check how many rows were changed. If zero row changed, then insert a new row for that date.

```
self.cur.execute( '''SELECT SUM(montant) AS totalsum FROM depances WHERE date = %s''',(date,))
result = self.cur.fetchall()
for i in result:
    o = i[0]

self.cur.execute( '''UPDATE total_jr SET total_depance = %s WHERE date = %s''',(o, date))

rowcnt = self.cur.rowcount  # number of rows updated - psycopg2
self.connection.commit()

if rowcnt == 0:  # no rows updated, need to insert new row
    self.cur_t = self.connection.cursor()

    self.cur_t.execute( '''INSERT INTO total_jr(total_depance, date) 
        VALUES (%s, %s)'''
    , (o, date))
    self.connection.commit()
```

Comment: hello thank for your reponce i'm using postgresql wheh i try this code it show me this error ` AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'affected_row' ` after searching apperantly i have to use the UPSERT ( i dont konw how to use it yet but its like im inserting a new row if it dose not existe and if it exicte it only update the total_depance

Comment: I updated the code for psycopg2. Using UPSERT may be better because it requires less calls to the DB.

Comment: hello again i'm sorry but it dose note work because in the first place the row dose not exicte so whene it run the isnert command the date will be empty and if i delete that row and try to run the function it do nothing thank you for your help i will try to learn how to use it with the UPSERT command thanx again

Answer (score 0):

You do not need 2 database calls for this. As @Mike67 suggested UPSERT functionality is what you want. However, you need to send both date and total_depance. In SQL that becomes:

```
insert into total_jr(date,total_depance) 
       values (date_value, total_value
        on conflict (date) 
        do update  
           set total_depance = excluded.total_depance;
```

or depending on input total_depance just the transaction value while on the table total_depance is an accumulation:

```
insert into total_jr(date,total_depance) 
       values (date_value, total_value
        on conflict (date) 
        do update  
           set total_depance = total_depance + excluded.total_depance;
```

I believe your code then becomes something like (assuming the 1st insert is correct)

```
self.cur_t.execute( ''' INSERT INTO total_jr(date,total_depance) VALUES (%s1,$s2)
        ON CONFLICT (date) DO UPDATE set total_depance = excluded.$s2''',(date,total_depance))
    self.connection.commit()
```

But that could off, you will need to verify.  

**Tip of the day**: You should change the column name ***date*** to something else. Date is a reserved word in both Postgres and the SQL Standard. It has predefined meanings based on its context. While you may get away with using it as a data name Postgres still has the right to change that at any time without notice, unlikely but still true. If so, then your code (and most code using that/those table(s)) fails, and tracking down why becomes extremely difficult. Basic rule do not use reserved words as data names; using reserved words as data or db object names is a bug just waiting to bite.

Comment: thank you very much @Belayer it's really help me better organise my code, and thanks for the Tip